# Borel linear order cannot have uncountable increasing chain

Tags: logic, descriptive-set-theory

I am trying to make sense of what this theorem from C.I. Steinhorn, *[Borel Structures and Measure and Category Logics](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235417282)*, says.

**Theorem 1.3.3.** *A Borel linear order cannot have an uncountable increasing or decreasing chain.*

I didn't find definitions in the paper, but I am quite sure that a pair $(A,\leq)$ is a Borel linear order iff $A$ is a Borel set in a standard Borel space $X$ and $\leq$ is Borel as a subset of $X^2$. I presume that an increasing chain is just a linear order with no greatest element and similarly for decreasing.

Here is the problem. Intuitively, I would guess that the lexicographic order on Baire space is a Borel linear order. But then Baire space itself should be an uncountable increasing chain under this order.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: This is true if chain is replaced by *wellordered chain*. In other words, a Borel linear order cannot contain a copy of $\omega_1$ or its reverse. I would guess that's what is meant, otherwise "increasing or decreasing" is not very meaningful. Where is this from?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais Does the well-ordered chain have to be Borel?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais The paper is linked to in the question. http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.pl/1235417282

Comment: @Rachel Mildly related to this result : A consequence of the Kunen-Martin Theorem asserts that all strict boldface $\Sigma_1^1$ (analytic) wellfounded relations have countable length. Boldface $\Sigma_1^1$ include the Borel sets.

Comment: I had missed the link! The author cites Harrington and Shelah, who did prove the result I recalled earlier. I guess it would be best to check that reference. @William: No. There are no uncountable wellordered Borel chains at all so that weaker variant is vacuously true.

Comment: @William Thanks, that's good to know. :^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference is to a result of Harrington and Shelah, who showed that a Borel linear order does not contain an $\omega_1$-chain. Since every uncountable wellordering contains an initial copy of $\omega_1$, it follows that a Borel linear order cannot contain an uncountable increasing *wellordered* chain. By reversing the linear order and applying the theorem again, we see that there are no uncountable decreasing wellordered chains either.

I conclude from this that the author probably meant for "chain" to be "wellordered chain" (which also explains the otherwise unusual phrase "increasing or decreasing").

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Elsevier's site is not letting me access the original article (though it should). I emailed them, so now I am just waiting to double-check it. I suppose you are right about "increasing", but what would you say instead, for a linearly-ordered set without a greatest element? I would think "unbounded" might be confusing here.